# html - can't remove white spaces between tables

Tags: html, css

i'm doing a html newsletter and i have two tables centered align. Between them exist a white line of 2 or 3px that i'm not being able to remove it.
The first table contain an "img" and the second table just text.
What can i try?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;vertical-align: bottom;">
  <tbody style="vertical-align: bottom;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
         <tr style="vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0;margin: 0;">
        <td style="vertical-align: bottom;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
          <img style="margin: 0;width: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0;" src="www.img.com/900x300.jpg">
        </td>
       </tr> 
    </tbody>
  </table>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;vertical-align: top;">
  <tbody style="vertical-align: top;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
    <tr style="vertical-align: top;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
      <td style="width: 900px;height: 160px;background-color: #2681ff;padding: 29px 23px 27px 36px;vertical-align: top;">
        <p style="width: 841.7px;height: 104px;font-family: ArialMT;font-size: 17px;line-height: 1.5;color: #ffffff;text-align: center;">
          BLA BLA BLA BLA
       </p>
    </td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: You could start by showing your actual html. Our magic crystal balls are all in the shop getting serviced, so we can't read your mind... and it's Friday, too. the balls that are done with the shop are probably out partying already anyways.

Comment: Did you set _margin_ to zero on the affected HTML elements? A default margin of nonzero could be responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: yes, i upload de html

Comment: Since you mention a newsletter, does that imply the HTML is being rendered by an email program? If so, which one? Email applications are notorious for having very poor/limited HTML/CSS support.

Comment: i use litmus for render it and test it

Comment: So you're viewing it on whatever Litmus provides to preview in your browser, not through sending a test email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One space is seen by HTML, you can remove it by commenting the space inbetween.

```
</table><!--

--><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;vertical-align: top;">
```

Hope it helps..